# Para que servem as tabelas temporárias?

Tags: sql

Qual a utilidade que essas tabelas denominadas temporárias podem oferecer?

Existe alguma vantagem em usá-las?

Existe diferença entre as tabelas temporárias e as tabelas "normais"?

Comment: Especifique qual sgdb está se referindo. Exemplo: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc

Comment: Daniel, a princípio não tinha essa pergunta em mente, mas pode ser tanto o sql server ou o mysql, porque são os que uso.

Comment: Votaram para fechar a pergunta? O que tem de errado nela? :O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ### Para que servem as tabelas temporárias?

Geralmente são usadas para processar ou armazenar temporariamente dados com tamanho variável em memória, quando variáveis simples não são suficientes.

> ### Qual a utilidade que essas tabelas denominadas temporárias podem oferecer?

- Você pode criar e destruir tabelas temporárias dinamicamente.
- Elas podem ter escopo limitado, por exemplo, uma instância diferente por conexão ou por *procedure*. Isso permite você processar dados em paralelo sem que um usuário afete os dados de outro o sem que uma procedure afete os dados de outra procedure.
- Você pode compartilhar dados entre procedures sem afetar o estado global do sistema. Por exemplo, você pode ter um processamento batch onde uma procedure extrai os dados das tabelas normais e passa o resultado para outra procedure que transforma os dados.
- Elas podem refletir a estrutura de dados de uma tabela "física" ou podem ter uma estrutura de dados para um caso de uso particular, como por exemplo dados extraídos para um relatório.
- Você pode armazenar temporariamente resultados de uma extração de dados demorada, tipo um cache.
- Em linguagens como T-SQL (SQL Server), elas fazem bem o papel de uma matriz ou um vetor dinâmico, na falta de tais estruturas de dados nativas na linguagem. Entretanto, elas nem sempre não são exatamente como matrizes, porque alguns bancos de dados permitem gerar números sequenciais ou mesmo índices em memória. Portanto, elas são mais "potentes" do que matrizes e ocupam mais memória.

> ### Existe alguma vantagem em usá-las?

- Elas são mais eficientes para processar dados, é claro, desde que a quantidade de dados não ultrapasse a memória disponível.
- Repetido, elas podem ser criadas e destruídas dinamicamente e ter um escopo limitado

> ### Existe diferença entre as tabelas temporárias e as tabelas "normais"?

Depende do banco de dados.

> Aviso: essas informações defasam rapidamente, pois a cada nova versão de um banco de dados, novas funcionalidades e tipos de dados surgem e outros são obsoletos. Sempre verifique na documentação **atual** do seu fornecedor qual é a melhor prática para armazenamento de dados temporários.

### Oracle

O Oracle, por exemplo, permite criar [tabelas temporárias globais](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html). Dependendo da configuração da tabela e da sua arquitetura podem haver problemas se as conexões forem reusadas a partir de um *connection pool* e as tabelas destruídas apenas no final da conexão. Para evitar isso você pode definir a limpeza da tabela ao final de uma transação.

[Exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE admin_work_area
        (startdate DATE,
         enddate DATE,
         class CHAR(20))
      ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Se você quiser limitar o escopo a uma procedure, por exemplo, pode usar `TYPE` para declarar uma estrutura parecida com uma tabela e que pode ser usada a partir de uma variável.

Exemplo de uma [variável de tabela](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#7658):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE StockItem IS RECORD (
      item_no     INTEGER(3),
      description VARCHAR2(50),
      quantity    INTEGER,
      price       REAL(7,2));
   item_info StockItem;  
BEGIN
   ...
END;
```

### Sql Server

Existem vários tipos, sendo os principais:

- Variáveis temporárias locais cujo nome inicia com uma cerquilha (`#`). Elas desaparecem quando nenhuma conexão as usam.
- Variáveis temporárias globais cujo nome inicia com duas cerquilhas (`##`). Elas permanecem em memória, são adicionadas no log e podem ser compartilhadas em diferentes conexões.
- Variáveis de tabela cujo nome inicia com uma arroba (`@`). Elas são como matrizes e ficam restritas ao escopo local de uma rotina, como uma variável local comum. São as mais rápidas para processamentos simples em conjuntos relativamente pequenos de dados.

[Exemplo de uma variável de tabela](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/):

```
DECLARE @FirstTable TABLE (RandomInteger INT)
```

É interessante notar que as tabelas temporárias são criadas num *schema* chamado `tempdb`, gerenciado pelo SQL Server. Isso não é muito intuitivo se você não tem um conhecimento sobre esse banco de dados e potencialmente pode levar a problemas de incompatibilidade de *collation*, quando um banco de dados tem uma codificação diferente do padrão da instância do SQL Server. Ao usar tabelas temporárias, sempre especifique o *collation* ao inserir, recuperar e comparar dados.

### PostgreSQL

Você pode [criar tabelas temporárias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html) com o mesmo comando de uma tabela normal. Assim como o SQL Server elas vivem num *schema* separado. Assim como o Oracle elas podem ser destruídas ao final da sessão ou ao finalizar a transação atual.

Você precisa recriar a tabela a cada nova sessão. Os dados não são compartilhados entre as diferentes sessões, mas a estrutura da tabela deve ser a mesma.

Para uso em rotinas, o PostgreSQL permite criar [variáveis com a mesma estrutura de tabelas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) usando `%ROWTYPE`.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_fields(t_row table1) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    t2_row table2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO t2_row FROM table2 WHERE ... ;
    RETURN t_row.f1 || t2_row.f3 || t_row.f5 || t2_row.f7;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT merge_fields(t.*) FROM table1 t WHERE ... ;
```

### MySQL

Permite usar o [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) para criar tabelas temporárias que são destruídas (conteúdo e definição) ao final da sessão.

Além disso, o MySQL é conhecido por ter vários tipo de *storage engines*, isto é, mecanismos de armazenamento. [Um deles armazena a tabela em memória](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html). A recomendação é usar para fazer um cache somente leitura após alguma extração de dados demorada.

## Considerações

Tabelas temporárias são diferentes em cada banco de dados e é complicado criar uma aplicação compatível com vários bancos que faça bom uso desse recurso.

O uso de tabelas temporárias, variáveis de tabelas e outros recursos específicos de bancos de dados são funcionalidades importantes que podem ajudar bastante quando se pensa no desempenho da aplicação. Entretanto, tais recursos devem sempre ser usados com cautela a fim de evitar perda de dados e consumo exagerado de memória. Basicamente, você precisa estudar exatamente cada caso para determinar se tabelas temporárias podem realmente ajudar e isto não é nada trivial quando se considera concorrência, memória, volume de dados e outras características.

Answer (score 5):

Tabelas temporárias são tabelas que só existem durante certo período de tempo.
Estou falando aqui em relação ao SQL Server. Então não existe bem um comparativo com as tabelas normais do banco.

As tabelas temporário servem para manipular dados durante um procedimento, seja ele somente no banco de dados ou da aplicação.

Imagine a seguinte situação. Sua tabela tem 10 milhões e de acordo com a sua consulta você só precisará de 10 mil linhas. Porém no seu processamento essa consulta filtrada é utilizada 15 vezes.

Ao invés de realizar a query 15 vezes você pode simplesmente criar uma tabela temporária com o valor da consulta e trabalhar com ela.

Comment: Isso então poderia tranquilamente trabalhar em conjunto com uma aplicação web?

Comment: @DiChrist sim poderia. Se você for processar diretamente esses 10mil de resultado sim. Mas agora imagine que esses 10mil seriam relacionados com outras tabelas e o resultado seria filtrado a partir de outra tabela.
Tabelas temporárias são mais indicadas para processamento a nível de banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi, mas em relação a essa vantagem que a tabela temporária pode oferecer, vi que pelo que você explicou, ela parece facilitar na hora de criar o código. Mas em relação a performance, ela é vantajosa também?

Comment: @DiChrist tabelas temporárias só existem na memoria RAM então sua leitura é muito rápida. Muito mais ágil.

Answer (score 2):

Tabelas temporárias são tabelas que
existem apenas durante a conexão com o banco de dados.
Ou seja, quando a conexão é encerrada, a tabela
é automaticamente eliminada.

Comment: Tabelas temporárias nem sempre duram somente até o fim da conexão. Depende to banco de dados e do tipo de tabela temporária.

Comment: Verdade @utluiz, em oracle por exemplo não deleta a tabela, apenas limpa os registros da tabela.

Answer (score 2):

**O que são Tabelas Temporárias:** 
Tabelas temporárias são tipos de tabelas que existem apenas enquanto a conexão com o banco de dados está ativa, após a conexão ser encerrada a tabela é automaticamente excluída, Esses tipos de tabelas é muito útil quando você precisa fazer algum tipo de tarefa simples e diária que necessite de tabelas e não quer ter todo trabalho de exclui-las então para isso existe as tabelas temporárias Que são auto-destruídas após o termino da conexão com o Banco de dados.

**Vantagens:**
Facilidade, rapidez, Simplicidade para tarefas simples e que não requer armazenamento de dados permanentes e sim temporários em tempo de conexão com o banco de dados.

**Existe diferença entre as tabelas temporárias e as tabelas "normais"?**
Sim Existe. As temporárias são auto-destruídas após o término da conexão com o Banco de Dados, Enquanto as Normais se mantem mesmo após o termino da conexão com o Banco de Dados.

Comment: Tabelas temporárias nem sempre duram somente até o fim da conexão. Depende to banco de dados e do tipo de tabela temporária.